# Redirect both domain and subdomains to https in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, https

How to use **RewriteEngine** to redirect both domain and all subdomains to **https** and `www.domain.tld` to `https://domain.tld` using relative path?

Currently I am using something like this

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} =80
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Which enables redirection of everything to `https` without `www`, I can see that some subdomains are redirecting as well, but **mail**`.domain.tld` is still available on `http`, no matter what I am doing.

> Note that I am running **[roundcube](https://roundcube.net)** on that subdomain and don't have access to this directory so I can't put another .htaccess to `mail.domain.tld` dir.

Comment: `mail.domain.tld` is controlled by `.htaccess` inside `mail.domain.tld` site root. You may use a redirect rule in Apache server config to redirect it but not in any other .htaccess

Comment: @anubhava I get that now, but I don't have access to mail dir, which is not actually part of my subdomains in hosting admin panel... So is there any other way to redirect mail? Like force roundcube to be accessible via https only?

Comment: okay I will simply ask my hosting provider to force https on roundcube :)

Comment: yes that would be best approach.